# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type : when I know the type is integer

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database where the values look like this:

```
Member Name: Amount of Warnings Given
```

Basically, I'm looping through all the member names and setting the number of warnings given to 0. But I keep getting the error "sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type."

This is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
  print ("Bot deployed to server")
  conn = sqlite3.connect(guild.name+"-database.db")
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warnings (name TEXT, amount_of_warnings INTEGER)")

  for member in guild.members:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO warnings VALUES(?,?)",(member,int(0)))
```

1. Why is it saying 0 is an unsupported type even though I made sure to make the "amount_of_warnings" an integer?
2. How do I fix this error?
3. Is there a way to do this better?

Comment: Parameter 0 is `member`, parameter 1 is `int(0)`

Comment: I think you want `member.name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`member` is a `discord.Member` object, you can't store that in the database. You need to use `member.name` to store it.

You can also make it more efficient by using `cursor.executemany()` to insert all the members at once.

```
params = [(member.name, 0) for member in guild.members]
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO warnings VALUES(?,?)", params)
```